# TypeError (0, ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function

Tags: testing, error

I keep getting this TypeError(0, ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function while running my test for my smart contract and I am very confused on how to solve it. On top of that, for my create listing test I am getting a cannot read properties of undefined reading(approve). I am new to testing so excuse my ignorance.

```
    import { loadFixture } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers";
    import { expect } from "chai";
    import { ethers } from "hardhat";

    let tokenId;
    let listingPrice;
    let owner;
    let horizonsMarketplace;
    let tokenIdSupply;
    let listToken;
    let token;
    let minter;

    describe("HorizonsMarketplace Initiation", function () {
    // We define a fixture to reuse the same setup in every test.
    // We use loadFixture to run this setup once, snapshot that state,
    // and reset Hardhat Network to that snapshot in every test.
    async function deployContractAndSetVariables() {
     const HorizonsMarketplace = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    "HorizonsMarketplace"
    );
    const horizonsMarketplace = await HorizonsMarketplace.deploy();

    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    return { horizonsMarketplace, owner };
   }

   it("should deploy and set the owner correctly", async function () {
     const { horizonsMarketplace, owner } = await loadFixture(
     deployContractAndSetVariables
     );

      expect(await horizonsMarketplace.owner()).to.equal(owner.getAddress);
     });

    describe("HorizonsMarketplace listing functionality", function () {
     it("Should create a new listing", async function () {
      await tokenId.approve(
      horizonsMarketplace.getAddress,
      listingPrice,
      owner
      );

      const tx = await horizonsMarketplace.listToken(
       token.address,
       tokenId,
       listingPrice,
       { from: minter }
       );
       expect(tokenId).to.equal(owner);
       expect(listingPrice).to.equal(1);
      expect(tokenIdSupply).to.increase(1);
      });
     });
   });
```

I might be missing a package instillation however I checked and updated my packages and everything should up to date. Not only am I getting this error for my specified contract but also getting it for the lock test script. So I am confused. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`getAddress` was used in v5 of ethers. From v6 onwards, you can simply use

```
horizonsMarketplace.address  
owner.address
```

About the second issue, you are calling the approve function on tokenId, which I belive is not a contract instance, instead you should be calling `token.approve`. Also make sure token contract is deployed, because I don't see any deployment for token in the test file itself.